# How to make responsive textfield on Header using MDL?

Tags: html, css, layout, material-design, material-design-lite

I have textfield in my header, I want to reduce the size for tablet and mobile phone access

Here is my code

```html
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">FyBox</span>

      <!-- Expandable Textfield -->
      <form action="#">
        <div class="mdl-card card-search">
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield txt-search">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input txtSearch" type="text" id="sample1"> @*
            <input type="text" id="sample1" class="txtSearch" />*@
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label lbl-search" for="sample1">Search</label>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Home</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">About US</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Contact US</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Search</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!--  Filters, it will show when the screen is small-->
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer mdl-layout--small-screen-only">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="page-content">
      <!-- Your content goes here -->
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

here is the image of my header [image]

Can I use Grid in Header? I never saw anywhere who used the grid in Header

Comment: I'd reconsider your header design, currently it looks almost identical to Facebook

Comment: @WhatsThePoint  oh my God. Even I didn't notice it